# How to style the appearance of a <select> when clicked?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've noticed that when you click on a `<select>` [element in Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms), the options that pop up have unstyled fonts.

Default element, with Helvetica text:

[image]

Unstyled element, with Arial(?) text:

[image]

Is there any way to style what appears when you click on a `<select>` element, or does this depend on the browser?

It's not very noticeable in base Bootstrap, but I'm using a different (serif) font, and it jars badly.

Comment: be aware that this may be an iOS specific issue

Comment: are you using bootstrap-select?

Comment: `select` elements are very, *very* difficult (and perhaps quite impossible) to reliably style with CSS. If the appearance is important, you're probably better off styling a `ul` or `ol` which is more receptive to styling, but requires JavaScript for functionality.

Comment: @scrappedcola - bootstrap-select looks really interesting, thank you!

Comment: @scrappedcola if you want to submit that as an answer, I will accept. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something similar to [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select). If you are when you have something like:

```
<select class='selectPicker'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

And apply whatever plugin you are using to prettify, this happens to your element:

```
<select class="selectpicker" style="display: none;">
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select open">
   <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix">
     <span class="filter-option pull-left">1</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>   
   </button>
   <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul style="max-height: none; overflow-y: auto;">
           <li rel="0"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">1</a></li>
           <li rel="1"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

So your css will have to target the `<ul>` that is actually showing your content. 
`.dropdown-menu{ font-family: serif; }`

Answer (score 0):

There are very limited options for styling `SELECT` boxes, however `font-family` should work:

```
select { font-family: serif; }
```

Comment: No, I've already got that in my CSS - it styles it OK when inactive, but not when clicked.

Comment: My guess is that there is other CSS overriding your font-family declaration.

Comment: Maybe so - if so, it's also there in Bootstrap base.

Answer (score 0):

i Think that in addition to  `select{font-family :yourFont;}`   you must Embed Font In CSS